# Jdom parser not recognizing special character attributes

Tags: java, jdom

problem in parsing special character attributes using jdom

ex

```
< tag xml:lang="123" >
```

this case `getAttributes()` method return `null`

is there any solution to fix this.

Comment: Can you show some of your parsing code?

Comment: sample tag : <element name="abc" id="10b0004" dm:goo="1" dm:use="use">

Comment: By parsing code, I meant the java jdom calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works without problems for me:

```
public class TestJdom
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    String xmlString = "<test><tag xml:lang=\"123\"></tag></test>";
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(new String(xmlString
        .getBytes()));

    Document doc = builder.build(stringReader);
    List<?> attrs = doc.getRootElement().getChild("tag").getAttributes();
    System.out.println(attrs);
  }
}
```

Comment: this way it is displaying in console fine when i try to read value it is returning null

Comment: works, too: System.out.println(((Attribute)attrs.get(0)).getValue());

Comment: before parsing its value i have to check whether attribute is exists or not

Comment: My example clearly shows that getAttributes() works correctly on your sample xml tag. So what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set namespace, check http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/programming/jdomexample.html